# How to set the exact number of rows that should be inserted in an "insert ignore ... select ..." query?

Tags: mysql, insert

Assuming I the result of the following query is 1000 rows:

```
SELECT * from table1 where ...;
```

If I want to insert only 100 of the select result into table2, solution would be:

```
INSERT IGNORE into table2 SELECT * from table1 where ... limit 100;
```

The problem is that, there may be some duplicate and therefore this query insert , let say, 90 records, where it actually can insert 100, for example if I set limit to 110 instead.

How can I fix this query?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT`? Delete the duplicates?

Comment: Use DISTINCT and the LIMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can likely select only those records that don't have a duplicate in table2:

```
INSERT IGNORE into table2 
    SELECT * from table1 
    where ... AND table1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2) limit 100;
```

This assumes the issue is caused by duplicate ids in table2 that appear in table1 triggering the ignore. You may also want to check out Ronak Shah's answer if your table1 has duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
INSERT IGNORE into table2 SELECT distinct * from table1 where ... limit 100;
```